# Prove that $X_n/\lambda_n \to$ 1 in probability for $X_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, poisson-distribution

> Let $X_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that $X_n/\lambda_n \to 1$ in probability

Should I solve this problem using chebychev's inequality? I'm not sure if setting $$P(\lvert X_n-\lambda_n\rvert\geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\text{Var}(X_n)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n(\epsilon^2)}$$ would help "prove" this relationship even though the term on the right side goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Chebyshev is a good idea.  However, you want to compute a bound on $Pr[|X_n/\lambda_n - 1|\geq \epsilon]$. Also, are you sure about your calculation of $Var(X_n)$?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the bound. For Var(Xn), doesn't it come out to (σx^2) /n, considering we are looking at the sample mean?

Comment: @Paul Please have a look at the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your questions are hard to read because of their formatting. (It is still unclear to me whether you mean $\lambda_n$ or $\lambda n$; your calculations suggest the second one...)

Comment: It actually turns out that $X_n/\lambda_n \rightarrow 1$ almost surely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chebyschev's inequality is indeed a very good idea, but you mixed up several things: First of all, we would like to estimate

$$p:= \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{X_n}{\lambda_n}-1 \right| \geq \epsilon \right)$$

(and not $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-\lambda_n| \geq \epsilon)$.)  Obviously,

$$p = \mathbb{P}(|X_n-\lambda_n| \geq \epsilon \lambda_n)$$

and therefore it follows from the Chebyshev inequality that

$$p \leq \frac{1}{(\epsilon \lambda_n)^2} \text{var} \, (X_n) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{1}{\lambda_n}.$$

Letting $n \to \infty$ finishes the proof.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I am new to the website and will definitely learn the basics. Thanks for your explanation, it is very logical!

Comment: @Paul You are welcome.